# How to integrate Facebook in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I am working on an ipad app where i want to integrate facebook in my app. I am using xcode-5.1. I followed the link on this URL : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ , but getting following errors :

```
Lexical or Preprocessors Issue
1. FBBatchRequestTests.h
'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file now found.
2.Semantic issue
Use of undeclared identifier 'FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING'
3.FBCAcheTests.h
Lexical or preprocessor Issue
'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h" file not found
4. FBCommonRequestTests.h
 Lexical or preprocessor Issue
    SenTestingKit/SentestingKit.h file not found
```

Please help me solve these errors. Also give me some related URLs for integarating facebook in ipad app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest tossing out whatever code that you are using to connect to facebook that is in that project and to follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app). It works. I have personally used it

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Facebook SDK 3.0 with samples and tutorials FROM FACEBOOK themselves. Download it from here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/07/facebook-sdk-3-0-for-ios/

You'll find the tutorials there too.